# iOS application launch from INRequestRideIntent extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, siri, sirikit

I need to implement a ride booking feature via Siri in an application. I managed to add extension to app and now I'm able to communicate with Siri, but I didn't succeed in launching app to continue ride booking process within the application.
So here comes the question, what should be done for launching app from INRequestRideIntent extension?

Thanks in advance!

**RideIntentHandler.m**

```
- (void)confirmRequestRide:(INRequestRideIntent *)intent completion:(void (^)(INRequestRideIntentResponse * _Nonnull))completion {
    INRideOption *rideOption = [[INRideOption alloc] initWithName:@"blah" estimatedPickupDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:300]];
    rideOption.userActivityForBookingInApplication = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:@"blahblah"];

    INRideStatus *rideStatus = [[INRideStatus alloc] init];
    rideStatus.rideOption = rideOption;
    rideStatus.estimatedPickupDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:300];
    rideStatus.rideIdentifier = [NSUUID UUID].UUIDString;

    INRequestRideIntentResponse *response = [[INRequestRideIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INRequestRideIntentResponseCodeSuccess userActivity:nil];
    response.rideStatus = rideStatus;

    completion(response);
}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleIntent:(INIntent *)intent completionHandler:(void (^)(INIntentResponse * _Nonnull))completionHandler {  
     [Utils showCommonAlertWithMessage:@"blah"];  

     if ([intent isKindOfClass:[INRequestRideIntent class]]) {  
          [Utils showCommonAlertWithMessage:@"blah"];  
     }  
}  

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {  
     [Utils showCommonAlertWithMessage:@"blah"];  

     if ([userActivity.interaction.intent isKindOfClass:[INRequestRideIntent class]]) {  
          NSLog(@"%@", userActivity.userInfo);  
          [Utils showCommonAlertWithMessage:@"blah"];  
     }  

     return YES;  
}  

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToContinueUserActivityWithType:(NSString *)userActivityType error:(NSError *)error {  
     [Utils showCommonAlertWithMessage:@"blah"];  
}
```